# HTTP request handler that sends an audio file from another URL as a response

Tags: express, http, google-cloud-functions, middleware, html5-audio

I want to allow users request audio files. The files are hosted on a separate file server. I don't want users to get these files unless they've gone through my server first.

How do I make a function that basically acts as a middle man between the user and the file server. I currently have something like this:

```js
async (req, res) => {
    const mediaLink = `https://www.example.com/audio.mp3`;
    const mediaResponse = await fetch(mediaLink, {
        headers: {
            Range: req.headers.range,
        }
    });
    const blob = await mediaResponse.blob(); // I'm guessing here. Idk.
    res.send(blob);
}
```

I tested this in an `<audio>` tag but the audio never loaded:

```html
<audio controls src="http://localhost:5001/file-server-middleware" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle such a request would be to [pipe the response body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#streams) back to the client making sure to copy across [any relevant headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header) that may be in the response from the file server. Read up on the [HTTP Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) to see what use cases you should be looking out for (e.g. CORS).

```js
async (req, res) => {
    const mediaLink = `https://www.example.com/audio.mp3`;

    // You may wish to pass through Cache-related headers, such as
    // If-None-Match, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since

    const mediaResponse = await fetch(mediaLink, {
        headers: {
            Range: req.headers.range,
        }
    });

    // note: this currently passes the body & status from the file server
    // as-is, you may want to send your own body on failed status codes to
    // hide the existence of the external server (i.e. custom 404 pages, no
    // Nginx error pages, etc)

    // mediaResponse.status may be:
    //  - 200 (sending full file)
    //  - 206 (sending portion of file)
    //  - 304 (not modified, if using cache headers)
    //  - 404 (file not found)
    //  - 412 (precondition failed, if using cache headers)
    //  - 416 (range not satisfiable)
    //  - 5xx (internal server errors from the file server)

    res
      .status(mediaResponse.status)
      .set({
        /* ... other headers (e.g. CORS, Cache-Control) ... */
        'Content-Type': mediaResponse.headers.get('content-type'),
        'Content-Length': mediaResponse.headers.get('content-length'),
        'Content-Encoding': mediaResponse.headers.get('content-encoding'),
        'Etag': mediaResponse.headers.get('Etag'), // for caching
        'Last-Modified': mediaResponse.headers.get('last-modified') // for caching
      });
    
    mediaResponse.body.pipe(res);
}
```

You may also want to look into the various [express-compatible proxy modules](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=express+proxy) that can handle the bodies and headers for you. Note that some of these may not function properly if used in a Firebase Cloud Function as the request bodies [are automatically consumed for you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request).